# GPO security filtering not working over Wi-Fi

Tags: group-policy

I currently have two separate power plans in my GPO object. The first one is for our virtual machines and the second one for our notebooks.

I applied item-level targeting to both of them and used the condition "Organizational Unit" to check whether it's a VM or a notebook. We store these in different OUs.

Now here's the strange part. When the notebook is connected to our network over LAN it works just fine. But when I switch to Wi-Fi, the item-level targeting does not work anymore and the wrong power plan is applied to the notebook.

Any ideas? Do we have to open a certain port in our firewall policy perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Check a similar case bellow I have read in the past and I think might have similarities with yours.

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1136031-gpo-over-wifi-not-working-win10-pro